# Renaming an xml doc filename

Tags: php, xml

I want to rename a file in php but it does not change the filename with what I have tried below.

```
 $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
    $incident = $xmlDoc->createElement("Incident");
    $root->appendChild($incident);
     blah blah......

    $tmp = split(" ", $entryTime);
    $dateString = $tmp[0] . "T" . $tmp[1];
    $entryTimeNode = $xmlDoc->createElement("EntryTime", $dateString);
 .........
    $xmlDoc->formatOutput = true;
    $xmlDoc->save($xmlFullFilename);
    $xmlDoc->rename("$xmlFullFilename","$entryTime_$xmlFullFilename");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOMDocument object does not have a `rename` method; you should use PHP's standard file `rename`:

```
$xmlDoc->save($xmlFullFilename);
rename("$xmlFullFilename","$entryTime_$xmlFullFilename");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $xmlDoc->rename() try php native rename function.

A sample.

rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");

This should work.

In your code,

> rename($xmlFullFilename,$entryTime_$xmlFullFilename);

Answer (score 0):

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) doesn't have **rename** method. Use PHP function [rename](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rename.php) for that.